# While normalizing ER Diagram what to do first ; ternary relationship or many to many relationship

Tags: many-to-many, normalization, entity-relationship, ternary, erd

I have designed a simple database **`ER Diagram`**, now I've to normalize it. I've a **`ternary operation`** in my **`ER Diagram`** they are:

```
Staff(StaffId,StaffName);

Student(StudentId,StudentName);

Opportunity(OppId{PK})
```

The `relationship_name` of these three is responsible and cardinality is **`Many-to-Many`**.

My question is what do first in normalizing , is it **`many- to -many`** relationship or the **`ternary`** relationship ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. By ternary operation, do you mean a ternary relation? If so, please show it - I only see three tables, none of which are ternary. What do you mean `cardinality is Many-to-Many`? If you're talking about a ternary relation, you should have 3 parts in that term, e.g. Many-to-Many-to-Many. Also, many-to-many binary relationships and ternary relationships aren't steps in normalization.

Comment: Okay sorry for that not explaining about much, these are the 3 entities Staff,Student and Opportunity which is in a ternary relationship, the relationship name is "responsibility" for all 3 entities. And the the all 3 relationship connecting to the  "responsibility" relationship have many-to-many cardinalities.

Comment: What do you mean by ternary and binary relationship can't be normalized, I've seen many-to-many cardinality are normalized in binary relationship by taking the common attributes into another entity.

Comment: Akila, if I understand correctly, you've got a table `Responsibility (StaffId PK, StudentId PK, OppId PK)`, is that right?

Comment: Normalization is a technique used to decompose tables to eliminate redundancy and inconsistency. What is redundant or inconsistent about many-to-many binary or ternary relationships?

Comment: @reaanb Binary & ternary relationships/tables can need to be normalized to projections too. Another problem is in ER "binary" & "ternary" refer to the number of entities involved, whereas there can be multiple table attributes per entity id plus other table attributes corresponding to ER attributes.

Comment: What is your textbook? What does it say to do? You need to show that you have tried to read & follow it, and say exactly where & how you are stuck. Normalization takes one table & possibly replaces it by projections of it. It doesn't matter what order you process the tables in. But cardinalites & FKs (foreign keys) don't matter, FDs (functional dependencies) & JDs (join dependencies) do. You don't write as though you understand normalization at all, why? PS Please edit clarifications into your question, not into comments.